# I need to clear filter when someone clicks on search box angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to clear the filter or when someone clicks on searchbox it should go back to `href`="#/"

`Code`:

```
<form name="search" ng-submit="search(asyncSelected)">
   <div class='input-group container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
      <input type="text" autofocus="" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search the directory by name" typeahead="user.sys_id as user.$$displayValue for user in getUsers($viewValue)" typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)" typeahead-focus-first="false" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" typeahead-loading="loadingUsers" class="input-lg form-control">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg directory" ng-click="search(asyncSelected)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>                                               
         </div>
      </input>
   </div>
</form>
```

My search `input`:

[image: Search input]

Comment: Can you provide more details? It is not clear what you mean. For example, do you want it to redirect when you click the search box? Or clear the location hash without reloading? Or do you just want to remove the text in the box when they focus in it (which is done automatically if you use the `placeholder` attribute)?

Comment: I added the code. So basically if user clicks on search box I want to redirect to home page. that #/

Comment: basically when someone search something results are displayed below search bar it adds some words in link. so if user click on search bar again i want to remove those words from link.

Answer (score 0):

just create one button for reset and set in your controller.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'search') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='search'}">
```

Comment: They don't want any buttons that's why I'm trying to figure out other ways to do it.

Comment: when you click text will empty right? i already edit my answer. you can try.

Comment: Thanks I just added ng-click="reset()" to my input and it worked.